# How to add categories for pages in WP?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there any way to add categories for each Page. I am asking it because I see categories option only for posts.

Answer (score 3):

You Can Add the following code in functions.php in your theme folder:

```
function myplugin_settings() {  
    // Add tag metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page'); 
    // Add category metabox to page
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
 // Add to the admin_init hook of your theme functions.php file 
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_settings' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think plugin [Add Category to Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-category-to-pages/) will help you to add categories with pages.